# sql performance - finding matching set in one to many table

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, innodb

I have a database table which stores SKU sets. So for example I might have the following individual SKU items:

- Circuit Board
- LED
- Battery Connector

Now I can sell these items separately, or I can sell them as a finalised item, i.e. I solder them together before posting them. (This is only an illustration so please don't comment saying let people solder them together themselves).

However with a SKU you create all possible combinations of items, so you could have all those three items separately, two together, three together, etc. So without further ado here is my SKU table:

```
TABLE `skus`

id | name
 1 : Circuit Board
 2 : LED
 3 : Battery Connector
 4 : Circuit Board + LED
 5 : Circuit Board + Battery Connector
 6 : Circuit Board + LED + Battery Connector
```

So we have all combinations as saleable units. Now in addition to this I want to know which individual SKUs build up those collections so that I can allow users to build their electronic devices on the website and the system knows what the collective outcome of the items is. So I've create a `sku_sets` table.

```
TABLE `sku_sets`

id | collective_sku_id | child_sku_id
 1 :         4         :       1
 2 :         4         :       2
 3 :         5         :       1
 4 :         5         :       3
 5 :         6         :       1
 6 :         6         :       2
 7 :         6         :       3
```

This table now allows me to find out what `sku` 4,5,6 are built from.

When the user therefore selects the Circuit Board, LED, and Battery Connector on the website and specifies they want the item pre-built, I need the system to be able to work out that the SKU matching that specification is number 6.

So far I have worked out the following query:

```
SELECT `collective_sku_id`
FROM  `sku_sets` 
WHERE `collective_sku_id` IN (
    SELECT `collective_sku_id`
    FROM `sku_sets`
    GROUP BY `collective_sku_id`
    HAVING COUNT( `collective_sku_id` ) = 3 // the number of SKU components
)
AND `child_sku_id` IN ( 1, 2, 3 ) 
GROUP BY `collective_sku_id`;
```

As you can see I'm using a sub query in the middle which is going to read all rows from the `sku_sets` table then find which ones have a `collective_sku_id` which occurs three times (this is so when I look for two components I don't also get collections for the two specified components and additional ones).

So the main question is how can I optimise, or produce a better query (or perhaps table structure) for what I want to achieve above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the HAVING COUNT outside:

```
SELECT `collective_sku_id`
FROM  `sku_sets` 
WHERE `child_sku_id` IN ( 1, 2, 3 ) 
GROUP BY `collective_sku_id`
HAVING COUNT( `collective_sku_id` ) = 3;
```

Then to address the situation where you want to match exactly the child_sku_id's and that doesn't have more than the ones you choose, you can do:

```
SELECT `collective_sku_id`
FROM  `sku_sets` s
WHERE s.`child_sku_id` IN ( 1, 2) 
AND s.`collective_sku_id` NOT IN 
    (SELECT `collective_sku_id` 
     FROM `sku_sets` ss1
     WHERE ss1.`child_sku_id` NOT IN ( 1, 2) )
GROUP BY `collective_sku_id`
HAVING COUNT( `collective_sku_id` ) = 2;
```

This last part i'm not sure how you can do without the NOT IN

EDIT:

Solution adopted by OP is in the comments:

> have a record of the number of components on the original sku table

This makes it easier to query without having to go with the subquery.

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8e488/16)</kbd> 
(updated)

Comment: Just tried this against my database. If I remove 3 from the `child_sku_id` and change the HAVING condition to `2` it return two results when it should only match the one with the two children skus. Same thing happens with your fiddle, so not quite correct.

Comment: I see. The query doesn't know you want the records with exactly two, it will return all the records that match it. But your previous query does that too. You may have to exclude the ones that have some records outside the IN statement. I updated my answer with something doing that.

Comment: I was thinking an idea might be to have a record of the number of components on the original `sku` table. I believe that would make the initial sub query quicker.

Comment: Yes that would make it faster, because you wouldn't have an inner query, you would just do an inner join with skus and check for the number. The inner query executes once for every row and the inner join executes only once.

Comment: Sounds like a good solution. I'll accept your answer... might be worth highlighting the solution is in the comments for any readers.